# Child selector rule in CSS

Tags: css, syntax, sass

I read "[Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS)"

> > Tag category rules should never contain a child selector
>
> Avoid using the child selector with tag category rules. This will
>   dramatically lengthen the match time (especially if the rule is likely
>   to be matched) for all occurrences of that element.

```
BAD
treehead > treerow > treecell {…}

GOOD
.treecell-header {…}
```

But in SCSS many people write something like this:

```
#main {
  width: 97%;

  p, div {
    font-size: 2em;
    a { font-weight: bold; }
  }

  pre { font-size: 3em; }
}
```

In SASS documentation - http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Who is right? What better?

Comment: Just a good read about nesting stuff on SASS: http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css specification is correct, you shouldn't nest selectors.

You're allowed to do that on SCSS because it will be compiled into separate class selectors.

For example, see this description on parent nested selection:

> ... if you have a deeply nested rule, the parent selector will be fully resolved before the & is replaced

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_

Comment: After Compass it looks - `#main p a {font-weight: bold;}`. No?

Comment: Yes... In your provided code, probably `#main p, #main div { font-size: 2em } ` and `#main p a, #main div a { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: Is it bad code? If yes, SASS documentation provides bad code.

Comment: No it's not bad code... SASS has its advantages, like parent selection that is resolved on compilation... In the end it will all be converted to the right form

Comment: Got it. Thank you. But can't find how convert to right code. Looking...

Answer (score 0):

Nested `.scss` tags don't expand into the child selector `>`.

```
#main {
    p {
        font-family:arial;
    }
}
```

Will expand to:

```
#main p {
    font-family:arial;
}
```